# STAG Vehicle Theft

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I just beat the main story to Saints Row the Third and I am going for my second platinum trophy for the PS3. I am moving onto the side mission and one of the objectives is to steal a STAG truck.

Since I already drove STAG out of town is there any possible way for me to get a STAG truck without having to go back?